# My lazycolumn items and my textfield glide on the screen when the keyboard is opened in jetpack compose

Tags: android

I'm just at the beginning of a chat bot application and I'm showing dialogs with lazycolumn. I also have a textfield, the bot responds to the texts entered in this textfield and `cards` appear on the screen, but when the keyboard is opened, my lazycolumn items slide upwards and the textfield does not appear properly. To solve this, I used something called `bringIntoViewRequester` and

I added the following to
my

**manifest** `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

**MainActivity** `window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)`

I'll share my codes below.

How can I solve this problem? also this method as far as I know is experimental, in my opinion if there is another non experimental method you know it would be better

[image]

[image]

**my first screen**

```
var index = 1

@Composable
fun FirstScreen() {

    val list = remember { mutableStateListOf<Message>() }

    val botList = listOf("Peter", "Francesca", "Luigi", "Igor")
    val random = (0..3).random()
    val botName: String = botList[random]

    val hashMap: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap<String, String>()

    customBotMessage(message = Message1, list)
    
    LazyColumn {
        items(list.size) { i ->
            if (list[i].id == RECEIVE_ID)
                Item(message = list[i], botName)
            else
                Item(message = list[i], "User")
        }
    }
    SimpleOutlinedTextFieldSample(list, hashMap)

}


@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun SimpleOutlinedTextFieldSample(
    list: SnapshotStateList<Message>,
    hashMap: HashMap<String, String>
) {

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val bringIntoViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }

    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier.bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                        if (focusState.isFocused) {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                            }
                        }
                    },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction.Done),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { keyboardController?.hide() }),
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { text = it },
                label = { Text("send message") })
            IconButton(onClick = {
                if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                 
                    list.add(
                        Message(
                            text,
                            SEND_ID,
                            Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString()
                        )
                    )
                    hashMap.put(listOfMessageKeys[index - 1], text)
                    customBotMessage(listOfMessages[index], list)

                    index += 1
                   
                }
                text = ""
            }) {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_send_24),
                    contentDescription = "send message img"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun customBotMessage(message: String, list: SnapshotStateList<Message>) {

    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(1000)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            list.add(Message(message, RECEIVE_ID, Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString()))
        }
    }
}
```

**LazyColumn - Item**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun Item(
    message : Message,
    person  : String,
   ){

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val bringIntoViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester),
        elevation = 10.dp
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp)
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)){
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
            ){
                Text(
                    buildAnnotatedString {
                        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Light)) {
                            append("$person: ")
                        }
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                            if (focusState.isFocused) {
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
                Text(
                    buildAnnotatedString {
                        withStyle(
                            style = SpanStyle(
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.W900,
                                color = Color(0xFF4552B8)
                            ))
                        {
                            append(message.message)
                        }
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                        if (focusState.isFocused) {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: set some contraints on LazyColumn so it is not the full height of the screen, you need it to be the height of the screen minus the height of the input text box

Comment: I couldn't understand clearly can you share some code please ?

Comment: check the height of your LazyColumn, and change it

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work sorry